# Three.js GLB texture is blur not clear

Tags: three.js, ar.js

I am trying to import a GLB model in my project. But the texture is blur can someone help here.

You can find the code [here](https://digitaladlib.com/ardemo/threear.html).

I have seen the model in the following viewer and the texture is much clear.
https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

I have also tried adding the getMaxAnisotropy() but it's also not making any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

Basically the problem was with the `renderer.setSize( 640, 480 );`

Just changed it to `renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );` and it solved the problem.